# custom select with popover, change color when open

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, select, popover

I've created a custom select with a div and ngbPopover.

Im stuck on how to style my 'select div' when the popover is open.
My select div should get a different border color when somebody clicked on it and thus the popover with all the options is open.
Whenever somebody clicks anywhere else and thus the popover is closing the border color of the select should go back to it's original color.

I've tried to do this with :focus or :active, but these don't seem to work..

Any ideas????

HTML:

```
<div [ngbPopover]="Category" triggers="click:click" placement="bottom-left" #q="ngbPopover" class="select" (document:click)="q.close()" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  {{ selectedCategory || 'All'}}
  <ng-template #Category class="options">
      <div *ngFor="let category of categories" (click)="selectedCategory = category.value" class="option" [ngClass]="{selected: category.value === selectedCategory}">
          {{ category.value }}
      </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
<span class="caret"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.select {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    color: #272727;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    width: 95%;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.6rem 1.2rem;
}

.select:active {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.options {
    width: 100%;
}

.option {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
}

.option:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.caret {
    margin-left: -2.5rem;
}

.selected,
.selected:hover {
    background-color: #4c59a8;
    color: #fff;
}

:host>>>ngb-popover-window {
    padding: 0;
    color: #adadad;
    width: calc(95% - 3rem);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 24rem;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

:host>>>ngb-popover-window>.popover-header {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @HostListener to accomplish your task. @HostListener listen events.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core'
.
.
.
class YourComponent {
  constructor() {
  }

  @HostListener('document:click') onDodumentClick(event: MouseEvent) { 
    // do your task here 
  }
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I ended up using a button to replace the outer div instead of your solution.
Your solution might have worked but I suddenly thought about the button and it turn out to be pretty easy for what I needed it to do.